# How to mirror gradient material

Tags: materials, modifiers

I have an object and applied mirror modifier with a gradient texture. The problem I'm facing is, the other mirrored object on the left, doesn't have the same texture coordinates like the original object on the right. Even on the right object I hade to change the settings of the mapping node, scale and location, so the gradient appears on my object.

The only way I figured out to fix it, was to apply the mirror modifier, and then apply the material to the left object, and then play around with the mapping node to make the gradient appear where its suppose to be located.

So what's the correct method to get the mirrored object to appear like the original object with all the materials, and to be in the exact location on the object.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you're using the Object's _own_ coordinates in the shader, you would just separate the X component and absolute value it. But it looks like you're using the coordinates for a differet Object, which makes it more complicated.

Comment: Is the object used in texture coordinate node intended? Or is it here because you're searching for a solution?

Comment: @lemon, I saw this node set up on YT, how to control gradients, so I have Object plugged into Vector, and move the location so the gradient can slide left-right, until I can see it on my object.

Comment: If you're using a mirror modifier you can check Mirror U or V and use the UV coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can make sure that the shader depends only on the absolute value of the X coordinate, since this is symmetric across the YZ plane.

[image]

Comment: So many great explanations, thanks so much guys. Always learning from this forum.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have to associate a coordinate-system with the mesh before the *Mirror* modifier gets to it. One way, as Gorgious suggests, would be to use UV mapping, and the facility provided by *Mirror*.

Another way might be to store the Position attribute on the mesh, above the *Mirror*, and then use that, in the shader:

[image]

Here, called 'Base P' in a 'Store P' GN modifier above the *Mirror*, and used like so:

[image]

For this result:

[image]